# Can't get OpenCV to work with Java+Maven+IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, opencv, intellij-idea, maven-3

I've seen lots of people asking similar questions to mine but their solutions aren't working for me. Here's what I've got:

I downloaded the latest OpenCV for Windows (2.4.9). I extracted this to C:\opencv-249

I then created a new Maven 3 project in IntelliJ.  This works fine and I can run the compile/package goals, etc.  I can execute and debug my program. This is all good.

Next, I tried to pull OpenCV into my test app and ended up with the following code:

```
package com.foo.OpenCVTest;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;

/**
 * Created by rick on 5/7/2014.
 */
public class RobotCntrl {
    static{ System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); }

    static public void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("In main!");
        System.out.println("Core Lib: " + Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

        Mat m  = Mat.eye(3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        System.out.println("m = " + m.dump());
    }
}
```

I then added the local OpenCV to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opencv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.9</version>
    <systemPath>${java.home}/../../../../opencv-249/build/java/opencv-249.jar</systemPath>
    <scope>system</scope>
</dependency>
```

And I added OpenCV as a project library:
[image]

And I modified the IntelliJ VM Options (Edit Configurations) to update the java.library.path to point to the OpenCV dlls:
[image]

When I run the application appears to load the opencv_java249.dll library just fine (it doesn't complain), but for the line:

```
 Mat m  = Mat.eye(3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1);
```

It bombs out complaining that it can't find the underlying n_eye() native function:

```
In main!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_eye(III)J
Core Lib: opencv_java249
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_eye(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.core.Mat.eye(Mat.java:1467)
    at com.aether.Robots.RobotCntrl.main(RobotCntrl.java:25)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm at a loss now. It's loading the wrapper library but it can't call the dependent functions. For the previous questions on similar issues, it tends to be resolved when people update their java.library.path variable, but mine seems correct:

`-Djava.library.path=C:\opencv-249\build\x64\vc10\bin;C:\opencv-249\build\java\x64`

or people forget to call System.loadLibrary(), but that call is succeeding (as far as I can tell) for me.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the output of `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vm.name"));`?

Comment: java.vm.name == Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

Comment: It has been a long time, but by any chance do you remember how did you solve the problem?